# Difference between two groups of unequal age

Tags: correlation, t-test, group-differences

This is probably a very simple question!  I am trying to compare two groups on a balance evaluation, a normal group and one with a neuro deficit. However, these two groups are significantly different in age. Since age is significantly correlated to the balance score, is there a way to compare my two groups while taking into account the effect of age?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information, including what is exactly the _balance score_? As it is not only statistics, maybe asking for help on http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ can help.

Comment: The balance score is actually a laboratory measure of sway.  Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add age as a covariate in a regression equation. However, if the two groups have no overlap on age, that may not be enough.

Comment: My two groups are actually overlapping in term of age. Thank you for your proposition. Just to make sure I get it right, were you referring to logistic regression, with group as the dependent variable and the balance score and age as covariates?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Not without more information. If you have enough overlapping data, you can follow Peter's advice, and use both variables in your regression. If not, you may be able to add in some information from previous studies on the relationship between age and the balance score. If the relationship is very robust, you may be able to adjust your data to account for the effect of age. However, be very careful when doing this, and make sure to clearly state your methodology and assumptions, so that you don't (accidentally) mislead your audience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The two groups actually overlap and there is a strong relationship between age and balance (older individuals tended to be less stable than the younger ones). How do I adjust my data to account for the effect of age?